# ChromeExtension: add new data to existing hash without overwriting the saved data chrome.storage.sync set/get API's

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, synchronization, storage

Implementing the chrome.storage.sync set/get API's, is there a way to add new data to an existing hash/array without overwriting the saved data?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out by default an existing key/value pair will be overwritten if writing new entries to a defined key. So I developed a workaround as a solution. The function retrieves strings from SelectedText on a given web-page & complies them in a chrome storage array creating a history of whats been highlighted in a popup.

Lets jump into the logic:

```
// Selected History Functionality
var history = [];
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
}, function(query) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('list', function(data) {
        if(typeof data.list == 'undefined' ) {
            chrome.storage.sync.set({'list': query}, function() {
                console.log("link key and value created");
            });
        } else {
            if(query != '') {
                var persistentData = data.list;
                history.push(persistentData, query);
                chrome.storage.sync.set({'list': history}, function() {
                    console.log("fetched and appended new data successfully");
                });
            }       
        }
    });
    document.getElementById('getHistory').onclick = function() {
        chrome.storage.sync.get('list', function(historyEntries) {
            document.getElementById('historyContainer').innerHTML = historyEntries.list;
        });
    }   
});
```

I'm retrieving whats persisted in storage & pushing it into an empty array that's out of the scope of the function along with the new entry & then overwriting the key/value pair, if it does not exist(the first entry) we create it. Then the data is passed to an empty div in the popup.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find a solution to your problem yourself. looking through your code I noticed a few things:

Comment: You're treating `query` as both a string & an Array. The [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#property-callback-result) clearly state it will be an Array of results. You should consistently treat it as an Array. You're using `==` and `!=` where it would be more appropriate to use `===` and `!==` (the latter should be `Array.isArray(query)` & should have an `else`. You add the `onclick` handler when the data in storage may be invalid, but you don't handle that case. You should use `addEventListener()`, not `onclick`. The `on*` properties are a bad way to add event listeners.

Comment: Thank you for commenting Makyen, I'm from Ruby where obj != '' or == is how we would check if not equal to a blank string / equal to. My research suggested I could use these operators in JS too. I shall experiment.. With regard to replacing != with( Array.isArray(query) else { do something } ) wouldn't that check if query is an array object? but isn't the query parameter always a string (  code: "window.getSelection().toString();" ) That condition is to stop blank entries ending up in the storage array object ( if icon is clicked without a page textSelection ) I will change the onclick  ;) TAR

Comment: The code/function posted here is only a part of the extensions backgroundScript, to check out the apps source in its entirety please go here https://twitter.com/WEBrip/status/891478294754807808 ( my Twitter ) Thanks again for commenting - I like that you made me question my code ;)  Kind regards Michael.

Comment: `query` is the value passed to the callback of [`tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#property-callback-result), which is always an Array of results (which means I should have suggested something else; my error; I was tired). Your `if(query != '')` converts the `query` Array into a string and then compares it to `''`, which will actually do what you want. But, if you're going to do that you could just do `if(!query[0])`. What you are probably really intending to do is `if(query[0] !== '')` which will use strict equality to compare the string returned with `''`.

Comment: The real issue is that you later `history.push(persistentData, query)`, which pushes the `persistentData` Array and `query` Array onto the `history` Array. Thus, assuming that you are repeating this action with the user selecting incrementing numbers, you would get `['1']`, then `[['1'],['2']]`, then `[[['1'],['2']],['3']]`, then `[[[['1'],['2']],['3']],['4']]`, etc. What I believe you desire there is `history = persistentData.concat(query);` (but that overwrites `history`,which may be bad elsewhere),or not use `history` and just `persistentData.push(query[0])` and then store `persistentData`.

Comment: Alternately, you don't need `persistentData` either and could just do `data.list.push(query[0])` and then store `data.list`, as there's really no need for either the `persistentData` or `history` variables (based solely on the code here, I haven't looked at your larger code).

Comment: All of your suggestions implemented & the application is functional( apart from .onclick - as I'm only using it once within specific functions it won't over write other event handlers )

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I'm posting this to better illustrate the comments above by Makyen & myself.This code is just part of the extensions background script, for anybody interested in viewing the file in its entirety please pop over here https://twitter.com/WEBrip/status/892386915915243523

History logic:

```
// Selected History Functionality
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
}, function(query) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('list', function(data) {
        if(typeof data.list == 'undefined' ) {
            chrome.storage.sync.set({'list': query}, function() {
                console.log("link key and value created");
            });
        } else {
            if(query[0] !== '') {
                data.list.push(query[0]);
                chrome.storage.sync.set({'list': data.list}, function() {
                    console.log("fetched and appended new data successfully");
                });
            }       
        }
    });
    getHistory.onclick = function() {
        chrome.storage.sync.get('list', function(historyEntries) {
            document.getElementById('historyContainer').innerHTML = historyEntries.list;
        });
    }   
});
```